# FabricJS After rendering, group and control box have wrong position

Tags: html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to make grid and make it selectable. I have the following method for generating grid:

```
function getGrid(width, height, count, name) {

        var oGridGroup = new fabric.Group([], {left: 0, top: 0, width: width, height: height, selection: true});
        var gridCountCell = count || 5;

        gridSizeWidth = width / gridCountCell - 0.3;
        gridSizeHeight = height / gridCountCell - 0.3;
        var lineOption = {stroke: '#ccc', strokeWidth: 1};

        for (var i = Math.ceil(width / gridSizeWidth); i--;) {           
            oGridGroup.add(new fabric.Line([gridSizeWidth * i, 0, gridSizeWidth * i, height], lineOption));
        }
        for (var i = Math.ceil(height / gridSizeHeight); i--;) { 
            oGridGroup.add(new fabric.Line([0, gridSizeHeight * i, width, gridSizeHeight * i], lineOption));
        }
        if(name) {
            oGridGroup.set({name: name})
        }

        return oGridGroup;
    }
```

As you can see, I setup four properties when create group. The problem is the group is rendered in wrong position. It has some offset.But, if I delete `width` and `height` when create object then group has proper position, but I can't select it, because `width` and `height` are zero. This is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pevtwgcL/), run it and try to select grid, you will see the offset. Then, comment `width` and `height` to see difference.

How to fix it?

PS. I tried to use `setCoords` method, but didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by creating the lines first, then create a group passing an array containing the references to the lines:

```
var lines = [];
for (var i = Math.ceil(width / gridSizeWidth); i--;) {           
  lines.push(new fabric.Line([gridSizeWidth * i, 0, gridSizeWidth * i, height], lineOption));
}
for (var i = Math.ceil(height / gridSizeHeight); i--;) { 
  lines.push(new fabric.Line([0, gridSizeHeight * i, width, gridSizeHeight * i], lineOption));
}               
var oGridGroup = new fabric.Group(lines, {left: 0, top: 0, width: width, height: height, selection: true});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/pevtwgcL/2/

Comment: Do you know why it happens in my code? I am asking because, I have the same issue when add a new shape to the existing group? For example, we have button which add rectangle to selected group:  `var newRect= new fabric.Rect({...}};` `selectedGroup.add(newRect)`

Comment: Please use `addWithUpdate()` instead of `add()`, like this: `selectedGroup.addWithUpdate(newRect)`.

Comment: When you group a few objects Fabric modifies the objects' coordinates and keep them relative to the group center. The `add()` method just adds a new object to the collection and doesn't update its position, thus it messes up the group. So the safe method of adding an object to the existing group is by using the `addWithUpdate` method.